# WHERE句のORの順番で並び替えたい！

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM _table 
WHERE _tag LIKE '%新幹線%' OR _schedule LIKE '%新幹線%' OR _memo LIKE '%新幹線%'
ORDER BY ???_tag,_schedule,_memoの順で並び替えたい???
```

sqlを発行した際にWHERE句のマッチが早い順番で並び替えたいです。そのようなことがSQLで可能でしょうか？　また重複は許可したくありません。

上記の場合ですと、新幹線という文字が、_tag,_schdule,_memoのいづれかに入っている場合に、_tagにマッチしたものを優先的に、その次は_schduleに、最後に_memo内に新幹線という文字が含まれるレコードがほしいです。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 11, accepted):

こんな感じでできるんじゃないかと思います。

```sql
SELECT * FROM _table 
WHERE _tag LIKE '%新幹線%' OR _schedule LIKE '%新幹線%' OR _memo LIKE '%新幹線%'
ORDER BY
 _tag LIKE '%新幹線%' DESC,
 _schedule LIKE '%新幹線%' DESC,
 _memo LIKE '%新幹線%' DESC;
```

`LIKE` は適合すると `1`, 適合しないと `0` を返します。`1`→`0` の順に並べるために `DESC` を使用しています。